# Unable to clone a git repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a git repository but I am getting this error.

```
fatal: unable to access
'https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2.git/':  Failed to
connect to 10.1.1.9 port 8080: Timed out
```

Earlier I was behind the proxy in my college but I am now using my home internet.

I tried disabling proxy using command `git config --global --unset core.gitproxy` but still getting that fatal error.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

EDIT: I have tried everything you guys suggested but nothing is working.This is the snapshot.
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Byzs.png)

Comment: *“10.1.1.9 port 8080”* – If you’re still getting *that* error, then you’re still behind some proxy.

Comment: Now I am not behind any proxy. My git shell is configured to connect to that proxy server that's why I am getting such error. I want to remove that configuration.

Comment: To help us answer the question, you should [edit] it to include the output of `git remote -av` as the port may be hardcoded into the remote's URL.

Comment: You have not checked your environment variable: `env|grep -i proxy`. If you see an `http(s)_proxy` or `HTTP(S)_PROXY`, you need to unset it (`unset http_proxy`).If you want to use .ssh, you need to generate and register your ssh key for your GitHub account: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Comment: @VonC yeah...It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: What worked? Did you unset an environment variable?

Comment: To moderators: this is 100% a Stack Overflow question and has nothing to do with Super User.

Comment: I did unset environment variable. But, after restarting the terminal it is again showing that error @VonC

Comment: Sure, it must be in your .bashrc or other profile setting files. Do a `cd; grep -i proxy .*` to be sure. I hjave edited the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any proxy directive anywhere:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy

git config --local --unset http.proxy
git config --local --unset https.proxy
```

Then check your OS environment variable. For instance, on Windows:

```
set http
```

That will display any variable (lowercase or uppercase) starting with http.
If you find any, unset them (`unset` on Linux, `set xxx=` on Windows)

---

The [OP Akhilesh Yadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5419740/akhilesh-yadav) confirms it is an environment variable issue

```
env|grep -i proxy
unset ..._proxy
```

Check the user settings:

```
cd 
grep -i proxy .*
```

Either a `.bashrc` or `.profile` could declare those proxy variables: edit the files and remove or comment those directives.

Answer (score 0):

try cloning via ssh as in `git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git`, that will have less issues with proxies.